# Assign dynamically a link in a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

we have a way to select a div and assign a text to it like as follows.

```
$(#divID).text("some text to show").
```

I want to put a hyperlink dynamically in the text to be shown in div. I mean the URL of the link will be passed from a method. Anyway to do it.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: USe `.html` instead of `.text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

```
$('#divID').html("<a href='www.go.com/mypage.php'>some text to show</a>").
```

or append to the existing content

```
$('#divID').append("<a href='www.go.com/mypage.php'>some text to show</a>").
```

Comment: You can also use chaining to make this a bit more readable; `$('#divID').append($('<a/>').attr('href', 'www.go.com/mypage.php').text('some text to show'));`

Answer (score 0):

You can append the link as html in the div like below

```
$("#divId").html("<a href='url'>hyperlink</a>")
```

it should work on all browsers.